# Algorithmic and programming complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

If a application stops reading from in-memory data structures, but from a 
vocabulary implemented on storage externally to main memory how does this affect algorithmic and programming complexity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't change the algorithmic complexity, unless you need to implement additional algorithms to perform your external storage protocol (normally that's not the case).

Programming complexity will probably increase (though it's most likely negligible)  in order to support the additional functionality.